# Unable to install python packages:ujson, blist, psutil and many more using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install some python libraries such as ujson, blist, psutil and many more using pip but I get the same error every time.

```
 In file included from blist/_blist.c:38:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: 
fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

The same error keeps repeating everytime. I have already updated pip to the latest version. Is there any other way to download these libraries ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I followed your link and re-installed command line tools (gcc) and python on my mac. But now I get a new error when I run 'pip install ujson'. The error is : clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Sorry the complete error is :   ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture x86_64. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)